# How can I spilt an array into multiple arrays when a specific item comes?

Tags: python, arrays

So is there a way to spilt an array into multiple when a specific item comes? For example I want to cut off and spilt the array everytime `SPILT` comes. The result should be like:

```
original = ["item", "anotherItem", "SPILT", "Item1", "item2"]
array1 = ["item", "anotherItem"]
array2 = ["Item1", "item2"]
```

Also the array can change so the index of `SPILT` is not certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `SPILT` is present just once, this should work:

```
array1 = original[:original.index('SPILT')]
array2 = original[original.index('SPILT')+1:]
```

Comment: I think "SPILT" comes multiple times, but yeah, your solution is best for singular instances of "SPILT". I have left a solution for dealing with multiple occurrences.

Comment: Yeah, it really depends on the original array.

Answer (score 2):

```
original = ["item", "anotherItem", "SPILT", "Item1", "item2"]

#Is the final array which contains all the split arrays
newarr = []
#Is a temporary array that stores the current chain of elements
currarr = []
for i in original:
    #if the splitting keyword is reached
    if i=="SPILT":
        #put all the current progress as a new array element, start afresh
        newarr.append(currarr)
        currarr = []
    else:
        #just add the element to the current progress
        currarr.append(i)
#add the final split segment of the array into the array of split segments
newarr.append(currarr)

print(newarr)
```

The comments have the necessary explanation. Intuitive solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

```
divider = original.index("SPILT")
print(divider)

array1 = original[:divider]
array2 = original[divider+1:]
print(f"{array1}, \n{array2}")
```

Answer (score 1):

If SPLIT occurs multiple times, then this should work.

```
original = ["item", "anotherItem", "SPLIT", "Item1", "item2", "SPLIT", "Item3", "item4"]
if 'SPLIT' in original:    
    test = '$'.join(original)
    splited_arrays = [data.split('$') for data in test.split('$SPLIT$')]
```

Comment: This is assuming $ doesn't appear anywhere in the strings in just the right way to screw your approach. Otherwise pretty neat solution.

Comment: @Prometheus You can replace $ with anything unique, that shouldn't cause any problem.